# Windows 7 can't connect to the Internet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have at home a network of 3 PCs (all Windows 7), 4 cellphones, 2 gaming consoles and a printer connected to the same router (Netgear D7000 Nighthawk); every single device is able to connect to the Internet and to the home network without problem, but I have a 4th laptop (windows 7 32 bit) which can't connect to the wifi, only via LAN cable.
It can establish a connection to the Wifi network, it can see and can be seen in the home network, it pings the router with a lag of 2ms but it doesn't connect to the external network. It can't ping any external website as well as any external IPs, giving me a "general failure" error.
Here's what I've tried so far:

- Flushing DNS list
- Flushing IP table
- Giving it manual IP address and DNS
- Giving it automatic IP address and DNS
- Disable IPv6 connection
- Completely removed and reinstalled up-to-date Wifi drivers
- Temporary mode with networking (is it called temporary mode in English?)
- Changing DNS at the router (pretty much pointless since every other device connected to it doesn't have a problem with the network)
- Giving it a fixed IP from the router
- Disabling Avast antivirus, Avast firewall and Windows firewall
- netsh interface ipv4 reset and ipv6 reset
- Voodoo magic
- Begging
- Hitting it with a baseball bat
- ???

Nothing of the above has worked so far. It's a computer that sits all day on the desk and act as a home server for my external drives, so I don't install any program on it, it just sits there.
I know that I could just format it, but it took me so long to configure it as a multimedia server, and I don't really fancy doing it again.
Some technical details:

Windows 7 32 bit, Intel core i3 M 350, 4GB RAM, Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000.

I am completely at loss, any idea will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do a '`route print`' on command line. Make sure you've got a default gateway there. `ipconfig /all` may also help. Do trace to some domains and some ip addresses:

```
tracert -d 4.2.2.2
tracert yahoo.com
```

If tracert doesn't go ahead a few hops the problem is with default gateway settings. If it does only for 4.2.2.2, you have DNS problem. Check settings and make sure everything is properly assigned by the router and there is no manual settings regarding that.

Comment: [here's the route print](https://imagebin.ca/v/3xekQhaqiytN) and [here's the tracert](https://imagebin.ca/v/3xekCxrXQfUm). It has the right default gateway (my router address) even in ipconfig /all and everything should be automatically assigned. The error in tracert translates to "generic error".

Comment: try ping to the router

Comment: average lag 1ms, no packet lost, TTL=64.

Comment: I reckon that is something with your router's wifi config. May be VLAN settings are set, or wrong access control preventing wifi clients.

Comment: I can't see how since, as I said, every other device connected to the wifi just works without problem.

Comment: MAC filtering, restricted number of clients on the router, and last but not least: disable builtin-in wifi and try a wifi usb dongle!

Comment: checked all of that and nothing, and besides, this laptop used to be connected on the wifi on the same network without problem. I've just tried another known working dongle and still doesn't work.

Comment: All tries you have done seemed to be on the system itself. Perhaps it's time to focus on the router. By the way, are you disabling LAN while connecting via Wifi? Cuz having both LAN & WiFi connected to the same router can be troublesome.

Comment: It's disconnected from the LAN but the adapter itself is not disabled. Can give it a try tonight. BTW the router firmware is up to date, last update was yesterday but still no change.

Comment: I've disabled the LAN adapter but nope, no luck. At this point I just give up and I'll be formatting soon. Thanks for your help anyway.